# Bad resolution from Displayport converter on third of three screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, amd-radeon, displayport, adapter

I am currently using three screens at the same time with my ATI 5770 & an active Displayport converter

The thing is that the third screen (the one using the active Displayport converter) is showing terrible resolution compared to my other two screens. All of my screens are the same brand and size. The monitors are named  Samsung Syncmaster P2350.

Two of my screens have a max resolution of 1920x1080, meanwhile the third on is only capable of 1600x1200.

Apparently the third screen is a Generic Non-PnP Monitor.

Do any of you know a solution to this problem?

Comment: does the "third monitor" work properly if it's the only monitor connected?  or does it show the same problems?

Answer (score 1):

If Windows detects a monitor as "Generic Non-PnP Monitor" it means it cannot identify the monitor or does not have an appropriate driver for it.  You could try searching the web and manually installing a driver for your monitor.  Perhaps the converter somehow prevents Windows from correctly detecting the monitor.

Or there could be a problem with the cables - sometimes loose pins/wires can cause these kind of strange problems also.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where my monitor would only display 1200x800.

I downloaded a new driver (a .inf file from LG)
I applied it to the "generic Non-PnP monitor in device manager, and now I can run 1920x1080 agian